# show or hide section on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I am trying to create a section, its just like jquery tabs. But instade of clicking i want it to work on mouse hover. Its working now but its buggy. If I hover over the specific section is showing but if I move the cursor and hover again on the same area it is not working. How can I fix it. (html cannot be changed).

```
<div class="section-option">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="color-option-1 active"> </div>
      <p>JBL Clip2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="color-option-2"> </div>
      <p>Bluetooth</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="color-option-3"> </div>
      <p style="word-wrap: unset !important;">Wasserdicht</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="color-option-4"> </div>
      <p>Akku</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="color-option-5"> </div>
      <p>Audiokable</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="color-option-1" class="color-option">
  <p>content 1 </p>
</div>
<div id="color-option-2" class="color-option hide">
  <p>content 2 </p>
</div>
<div id="color-option-3" class="color-option hide">
  <p>content 3 </p>
</div>
<div id="color-option-4" class="color-option hide">
  <p>content 4 </p>
</div>
<div id="color-option-5" class="color-option hide">
  <p>content 5 </p>
</div>


$(".section-option li")
        .mouseenter(function () {
            $id = $(this).children("div").attr("class");
            $(".color-option").addClass("hide");
            $(".section-option li div").removeClass("active");
            $("#" + $id).removeClass("hide");
            $(this).children("div").addClass("active");

        })
        .mouseleave(function () {


        });
```

Comment: Why don't you try CSS `:hover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".section-option li").hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).children("div").attr("class").split(' ')[0];
    $("#" + id + "").toggleClass("active").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

I have added the `split()` method because without it wouldn't work for the first `li`, as there are two classes (`color-option-1` and `active`).

Comment: thanks it is working, but there is a problem. the first option is getting always selected and the first content is visible. how can we disable the first option when hoved on other div? if not any div hovered it should show the first one

Answer (score 0):

Simple, because the first time you are adding an `active` class to your `div`.

Next time if you hover over that, the class of the div has active plus the `id` which gives you the wrong selector.

You have two option:

1- Add `active` class to `li` instead of `div`

2- When you are getting the class of div, remove the `active` if any